# Converting MySQL "get top y for each n" GROUP BY query to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pg

Ok so I'm going from mysql to postgresql because of Heroku. I have this statement that works perfect in mysql, but I can't seem to figure out the best way / any way for PG.

```
m = C.select("m.derp, c.id").joins("join m on m.c_id = c.id").where("m.id IN (SELECT max(id) from m group by c_id order by updated_at desc)").order("m.updated_at desc")
```

So basically I need to grab m's as grouped by c, ordered by the latest created m's. Postgres won't let me select multiple columns without them being in the group by call, which will give me more rows than I want. Otherwise I'll get the

```
column X must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having to do some guesswork here because of the mixture of Rails-y query builder code and real SQL. It'd help if you showed the actual SQL.

Comment: I'm trying to find the latest message from distinct conversations. In my example m = Message, m.derp = Message.message, and c = Conversation. Conversation has_many messages
so in plain english:
Find latest created message from distinct conversations and show their message. 
The lastest created obviously can be from a desc id, created_at, or updated_at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue on migration to Pg, because MySQL permits you to write non-standard `GROUP BY` clauses that may have non-deterministic results.

If you:

```
SELECT a, b FROM sometable GROUP BY a;
```

and there's >1 distinct value for `b` in the table, how does the database know which row to return?

For PostgreSQL, if you want this kind of behaviour [you must use the `DISTINCT ON` extension instead](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), as PostgreSQL follows the standard by rejecting possibly non-deterministic `GROUP BY` clauses. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a, b FROM sometable ORDER BY a;
```

... assuming that this is really what you intended. Your question doesn't really cover the underlying problem you're trying to solve - *why* you're trying to do this - so it's hard to say if this is the right approach.

---

*Update*: Based on the explanation in the comments, in your case I think you can use a correlated subquery with `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` and an equality test, instead of your current uncorrelated subquery with `IN`.

Translating your Rails-code to SQL, I get something like:

```
SELECT m.derp, c.id
FROM c
INNER JOIN m ON m.c_id = c.id
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT max(id) from m group by c_id order by updated_at desc)
ORDER BY m.updated_at desc;
```

which you explain as being intended to find the newest message on each conversation.

If so, instead try:

```
SELECT m.derp, c.id
FROM c
INNER JOIN m ON m.c_id = c.id
WHERE m.id = (SELECT m2.id FROM m m2 WHERE m2.c_id = c.id ORDER BY m2.updated_at LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY m.updated_at desc;
```

The subquery runs once for each outer `c` row, so it's vital that `m.c_id` have an index. In fact, I think it'll perform best with an index on

```
m (c_id, updated_at)
```

or if you're on PostgreSQL 9.2 or above with index-only scan support, possibly:

```
m (c_id, updated_at, id)
```

though I'd need to test both those with dummy data and schema to be 100% sure.

Comment: I'm trying to find the latest message from distinct conversations. In my example m = Message, m.derp = Message.message, and c = Conversation.

Conversation has_many messages

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing So for each conversation you want the subquery to produce the ID of the newest message in that conversation? If so, yes, `DISTINCT ON` is what you want. There is unfortunately no efficient and portable way to write this in standard SQL - it's possible with window functions, but slower, and wouldn't help you because MySQL doesn't support window functions.

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing In your case I think you're better off using a correlated subquery with `LIMIT` (also non-standard, but should be fine in MySQL too), per the edit above.

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing Glad to hear it. It'll be *much* more efficient in cases where the outer query has a filter that limits it to a subset of conversations, too.